# Php array offset passes 'isset', even though it's not set

Tags: php

The easiest way for me to explain this is to show an example ... Here's a replication of the problem code:

```
<?php
    $test=array();
    $test['one']='hello';
    if(isset($test['one']['two'][0])) {
        echo 'Apparently it is set ...';
        echo $test['one']['two'][0];
   }
?>
```

This returns as:

> Apparently it is set ...
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'two' in C:\test.php on line 6
>
> h

Is this because there are mixed key types? It's just a little anomaly I came across and was wondering if someone could shed some light on it ...

Comment: This behaviour changed in 5.4, [3v4l results](http://3v4l.org/9XJg6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that, when you dereference a string, it will return a string comprising a single character (assuming the index doesn't exceed the length); the resulting string can be dereferenced again (starting from 5.4 onwards).

For example - [link](http://3v4l.org/dBOsK):

```
$s = 'hello';
$s[0];    // "h"
$s[0][0]; // "h"
// etc. etc.
```

*Illegal indices such as `'two'` will cause a notice but it's treated as index `0`, except when used inside `isset()`.*

Another example:

```
$s[0][1];    // ""
$s[0][1][0]; // notice: uninitialised string offset: 0
```

If you don't know beforehand whether a string or array is passed and this is important to you, additional type checks need to take place in between each path.

Comment: Now that makes sense. But isn't the older one the correct expected result?

Comment: @bansi What do you mean by "the older one"? You mean prior to 5.4? I've added a [link](http://3v4l.org/dBOsK) that shows the two behaviours; you're free to make up your own mind which makes more sense, but personally I would say that the current behaviour is more logical.

Comment: in my point of view `$test['one']['two'][0]` is never set so it should return `false` instead of `true`. and in your example `$s[0] = h` is correct, but `$s[0][0]` should throw warning. This is just my personal view.

Comment: @bansi I would agree that an illegal index should yield `null` when applied to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your all your array keys exist before you try and use them, i.e. all the way up the chain. [`isset()` accepts multiple parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) so you don't need to keep rewriting it and can keep DRY principles going a little more:

```
$test = array();
$test['one'] = 'hello';
if (isset($test['one'], $test['one']['two'], $test['one']['two'][0])) {
    echo 'Apparently it is set ...';
    echo $test['one']['two'][0];
}
```

Comment: Scratch that, no it doesnt :D

Comment: But, why does my first example think that the key exists? It only happens when using the `[0]` key. if I replace the `[0]` with a string (`['string']`) it doesnt throw the error

Comment: @Stretch it's pass in isset cause it's checking $test['one'] and found true so goes in

Answer (score -1):

`isset` returns odd and unexpected results when you pass it a string instead of an array.

It is good practice to pair an an `is_array` check with an `isset` check.